# Getting value of a cell from a GridView on SelectedIndexChanged event of DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView that has *data bounded* rows. I'm trying to get specific cell value on the **SelectedIndexChanged** event of **DropDownList**. My tries are as follows:

```
string temp=  GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;

string temp = ((DataBoundLiteralControl)GridView2.Rows[0].Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text;

DataBoundLiteralControl dblc = (DataBoundLiteralControl)GridView2.Rows[0].Cells[3].Controls[0];
string temp=dblc.Text;
```

These all 3 of them returns *null*.

Moreover, the *Control[0]* is returning correct value of *TemplateFields* only, but not *DataBound* fields.

.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" HeaderStyle-BackColor=" #d54d7b" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
RowStyle-BackColor="#FFFAFC" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#FFFFF7" AlternatingRowStyle-ForeColor="#000"
 AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging" Width="900px" Font-Names="Segoe UI Light"  BorderColor="#DEDEDE">
<RowStyle HorizontalAlign="center" />
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" ItemStyle-Width="80"  />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Vacancies" HeaderText="Vacancies" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Detail">
     <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" ItemStyle-Width="80"  />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="Time" HeaderText="Time" ItemStyle-Width="80"  />

</Columns>
```

Comment: Is your Dropdownlist in the gridview or outside gridview. Can you post the .aspx code.

Comment: So you want to select `Date Column` from `GridView1` on `SelectedIndexChanged` of Dropdownlist?

Comment: @TFrost Obviously yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Converted all `<asp:BoundFields>` to `<asp:TemplateField>` and it looked like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" HeaderStyle-BackColor=" #009C0D" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
    RowStyle-BackColor="#FFFAFC" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#FFFFF7" AlternatingRowStyle-ForeColor="#000"
     AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true"  CssClass="test"
     HtmlEncode="true" 
        Font-Names="Segoe UI Light"  BorderColor="#DEDEDE" >
    <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="center" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" ControlStyle-Width="250px"  ><ItemTemplate> <asp:LinkButton  ID= "Description" PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("Description", "~/{0}.aspx") %>'    Text='<%# Eval("Description")%>'  runat="server" ></asp:LinkButton>   </ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vacancies"><ItemTemplate>   <asp:Label ID="Vacancies"  Text='<%# Eval("Vacancies")%>' runat="server" ></asp:Label>   </ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Detail"><ItemTemplate><asp:Label ID="City"  Text='<%# Eval("City")%>' runat="server" ></asp:Label> <div style="font-size:10px"> <asp:Label ID="Label1"   Text='<%# Eval("DateDay")%>' runat="server" ></asp:Label> </div> </ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
        //and others
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And get specific value by entering this code behind **DropDownList**:

```
 if (dropdown.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {

        ListItem mySelectedItem = (from ListItem li in dropdown.Items where li.Selected == true select li).First();
        foreach (GridViewRow rw in GridView2.Rows)
        {

            Label tv = (Label)rw.Cells[3].FindControl("City");

            if (tv.Text.IndexOf(mySelectedItem.Text) != -1)
            {
                rw.Visible = true;

            }
            else
                rw.Visible = false;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem you are probably facing is that, `GridView1` hasn't been `bounded` yet.. that is the reason why `Control[0]` is returning correct value of `TemplateFields` but `cells` in the `gridview` returns `null`.
You can do the following

```
protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    /// send value to filter or bind gridView1
    /// bind gridvew
    string temp = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Text;
    /// or any code to get values from GridView Cell

}
```

Comment: **GridView1** is bounded and also tried doing *.Text*.

Comment: Can you update the question and post ddlSelectedIndexChanged method.